# Packaging a directory and its contents as a diff patch?

Tags: bash, diff, patch

I have a small project folder with text files, which I'd like to post somewhere in order to ask a question on a forum. Let's take, in the simplest case, that I have something like this:

```bash
mkdir aaa
cd aaa
echo AAA > aaa.txt
mkdir bbb
echo BBB > bbb/bbb.txt
```

Obviously, I'd like the subfolder structure:

```
aaa/
├── aaa.txt
└── bbb
    └── bbb.txt
```

... to be preserved when I share this. So I thought first using https://gist.github.com/ and entering subdirectory names for each file; unfortunately github responds with:

> Contents files can't be in subdirectories or include '/' in the name

... and I don't intend to register there, just to be able to check out and commit subdirectories to the gist via `git`, for something like this (one would wish they accepted openID, but... eh).

So, I thought, maybe I can somehow package the entire directory structure and the file contents as a `diff` patch file; then as a single file, it should be easy to upload to a gist. However, I don't know how to specify a diff between my folder and an empty folder; I tried:

```bash
$ diff -Naur /dev/null /tmp/aaa
diff: /tmp/aaa/null: No such file or directory
```

... but clearly, that doesn't work.

However, in principle it should be possible - here is a test case via `git`:

```bash
mkdir aaa
cd aaa
git init
git config user.name test
git config user.email test@test.com

echo AAA > aaa.txt
mkdir bbb
echo BBB > bbb/bbb.txt

git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git format-patch -1 HEAD
```

At this point, a file `0001-initial-commit.patch` appears, with these contents:

```
From 5834ae98fad9a9148648577f366af3498be6d364 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: test <test@test.com>
Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 10:25:23 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] initial commit

---
 aaa.txt     | 1 +
 bbb/bbb.txt | 1 +
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 aaa.txt
 create mode 100644 bbb/bbb.txt

diff --git a/aaa.txt b/aaa.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..43d5a8e
--- /dev/null
+++ b/aaa.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+AAA
diff --git a/bbb/bbb.txt b/bbb/bbb.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..ba62923
--- /dev/null
+++ b/bbb/bbb.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+BBB
-- 
1.9.1
```

... which is approximately what I had in mind, except - I don't want any of the email headers and stat comments that `git` adds; and also I wouldn't want `git` to be required to reconstruct the folder from the patch file - I'd just want people to be able to use `patch` to reconstruct the folder and its contents.

So

- Is it possible to do a patch file like this using only vanilla `diff`?
- If not, is it possible to tell `git` to remove all git-specific comments, and format a patch as if it was produced by `diff` alone?
- In case there are small binary files there (i.e. spinner.gif and such), is it possible to instruct `diff` (or `git`) to include the binary data as base64, or other text encoding that would survive posting/pasting to a public service like gist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using only `diff`, you need a reference (empty) directory to compare things against:

```
mkdir /tmp/scratch
diff -urN /tmp/scratch /tmp/aaa
```

Using `git`, `git diff` should give you the output you're looking for.

To handle binaries, use `git diff --binary`; this will produce an encoded patch which `git apply` will know how to handle.

Comment: Is it safe to run `diff -urN` on the original directories, without copying them to tmp? Or it is possible that git will delete something?

Comment: `diff` and `git diff` don’t delete anything; this is safe anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to do a patch file like this using only vanilla `diff`?

With GNU diff, yes, if you include the `-N` option, and you don't care about empty directories:

```
$ tree a b
a
├── aaa
│   ├── aaa.txt
│   └── bbb
│       └── bbb.txt
└── ccc
b

3 directories, 2 files
$ diff -uNr b a | (cd b; patch -p1)
~/devel/b
patching file aaa/aaa.txt
patching file aaa/bbb/bbb.txt
$  tree b
b
└── aaa
    ├── aaa.txt
    └── bbb
        └── bbb.txt

2 directories, 2 files
```

> If not, is it possible to tell git to remove all git-specific comments, and format a patch as if it was produced by diff alone?

`git diff` could be used if there was an initial empty commit:

```
$ git init
$ git commit --allow-empty -m init
[empty (root-commit) d1d0a97] init
$ git add aaa
$ git commit -m 'foo'
[empty b834eba] foo
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 aaa/aaa.txt
 create mode 100644 aaa/bbb/bbb.txt
$ git diff 'HEAD^'
diff --git a/aaa/aaa.txt b/aaa/aaa.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..43d5a8e
--- /dev/null
+++ b/aaa/aaa.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+AAA
diff --git a/aaa/bbb/bbb.txt b/aaa/bbb/bbb.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..ba62923
--- /dev/null
+++ b/aaa/bbb/bbb.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+BBB
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @muru - good to have the snippet examples; cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The (somewhat) standard way to ship files and directories as text is to use shar(1). This creates a (somewhat readable) shell script that recreates the files/directories.

It is easier to just pack the stuff up with tar(1) or even zip(1), and have the recipient unpack.